# calling stored procedure inserts NULLs into all columns MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, sql-insert, database-table

I've created a stored procedure in MySQL to help debug something, however when i call the stored procedure it inserts NULL values into my table for all columns

Table

```
CREATE TABLE `EncryptionDebug` (
`ObservedValue` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
`PublicKey` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Stored procedure

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE `EncryptionDebug`(IN `ObservedValue` MEDIUMTEXT, IN     `PublicKey` MEDIUMTEXT)
MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN
    DECLARE `ObservedValue` MEDIUMTEXT;
    DECLARE `PublicKey` MEDIUMTEXT;

        INSERT INTO `EncryptionDebug` (`ObservedValue`,`PublicKey`) VALUES     (ObservedValue,PublicKey);
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Calling the procedure like so

```
CALL EncryptionDebug('test','test');
```

Returns NULL for both columns when i SELECT * FROM EncryptionDebug

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> [13.6.4.2 Local Variable Scope and Resolution](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/local-variable-scope.html)
>
> ...
>
> A local variable should not have the same name as a table column.
>
> ...

One option to try:

```sql
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE `EncryptionDebug1`(
    `ObservedValue` MEDIUMTEXT,
    `PublicKey` MEDIUMTEXT
)
MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN
    /*
    DECLARE `ObservedValue` MEDIUMTEXT;
    DECLARE `PublicKey` MEDIUMTEXT;
    */
    INSERT INTO `EncryptionDebug` (`ObservedValue`, `PublicKey`)
    VALUES
    (`ObservedValue`, `PublicKey`);
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2f8e9/1)</kbd>

**Recommendation:** Avoid naming parameters and variables as columns of your tables, here the cause: <kbd>[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6f480d/2)</kbd>.